# why i get last data in column sqlite android

Tags: android, logic, android-sqlite, inner-join

i want to get all title and theme_filepath on id of table book = book_id of table theme but i get a last title and theme file_path can you check a logic in my code please.

this is my code

```
public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> getBookTheme(){

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hm = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> list_book = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list_theme = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT title, filepath FROM " + 
                BooksDBHelper.TABLE_BOOK + " INNER JOIN " + BooksDBHelper.TABLE_THEME +
                " ON " + BooksDBHelper.TABLE_BOOK + "." + BooksDBHelper.KEY_ID + " = " + 
                BooksDBHelper.TABLE_THEME + "." + BooksDBHelper.KEY_BOK_ID + 
                " WHERE " + BooksDBHelper.TABLE_BOOK + "." + BooksDBHelper.KEY_ID + " != ? ", new String[]{Integer.toString(0)});
    cursor.moveToLast();
    if(cursor.getCount() != 0){
        do{

            list_book.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BooksDBHelper.KEY_TITLE)));
            list_theme.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BooksDBHelper.KEY_fILEPATH)));


        }while(cursor.moveToNext());

        hm.put("title", list_book);
        hm.put("theme", list_theme);
    }

    return hm;

}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `cursor.moveToLast()`.

Consider replacing

```
cursor.moveToLast();
if(cursor.getCount() != 0){
```

with

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
```